# How do I make a grid in python?

Tags: python, grid

This is my code

```
width = int(input("How wide?"))
height = int(input("How high?"))
grid = []
row = []
bak = "."
for i in range(width):
    row.append(bak)
for i in range(height):
    grid.append(row)
while True:
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[i])
```

It's not working and i don't know why. This is what i get when i put 5 width and 5 height:

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

That's fine and all but when i change the bottom left dot by using this: grid[0][0] = "a".
This happens:

```
['a', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['a', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['a', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['a', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['a', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

It thinks the "row" list is a tag, when it is clearly coded not to be.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: **Hint:** use an array of strings instead of a 2D array of chars. This will work because a string is an array of chars.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn: A character in a Python string cannot be modified, while a character in an array of characters can be. The OP shows that replacement is desired, so the two cannot be considered equivalent. You may be thinking of other languages where strings may be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list()

```
gridline = []
for i in range(5):
    gridline.append("")
grid = []
for i in range(5):
    grid.append(list(gridline))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in range(height):
    grid.append(row)
```

This `for` loop appends the same `row` list to the `grid` list (actually it appends 5 different references to the **same** list).

Instead, you should append a new, different list:

```
for i in range(height):
    grid.append([])
```

Verify by viewing the memory addresses of the inner lists in these 2 examples:

```
grid = []
row = []
for i in range(5):
    grid.append(row)
for li in grid:
    print(id(li))
# 92532104
# 92532104
# 92532104
# 92532104
# 92532104
```

compared to

```
grid = []
for i in range(5):
    grid.append([])
for li in grid:
    print(id(li))

# 80801224
# 80801160
# 80669704
# 80381192
# 80380488
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this.

```
    width = int(input("how wide "))
    height = int(input("how tall "))
    grid = []
    i = int(0)
    for i in range(width):
        grid.append("_")
    for i in range(height):
        print(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# creating grid
length = int(input("enter your grid length"))
breath = int(input("enter your grid breath"))
board = []
for i in range(length):
   board.append(["*"] * breath)
for x in board:
   grid = (" ".join(x))
   print(grid)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is four and a half years old) with existing answers.