# How do i create and display my dict as a grid?

Tags: python

I want to generate an alphabet grid with random numbers for the give-away letters displayed, which will eventually get filled in as the user tries to figure out the phrase.

My code:

```
import string, random
#User Input
title = input("Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: ") 
phrase = input("Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: ") 
#Numbers get assigned to the letters 
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
code = dict(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))

#'Start' of Puzzle for the user  
print (title)
#Giveaway Letters
print (code[3], "is number 3")
print (code[14], "is number 14")
print (code[4], "is number 4")
```

As you can see my dict assigns random numbers to letters of the alphabet and I need to create a grid that shows this. I have looked at [How do i make a grid in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910947/how-do-i-make-a-grid-in-python)? but am still unsure as to how I can implement it into this code hence this question.

Thank you

Comment: You can use pandas and convert them into a data frame

Comment: You can also try [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Irfanuddin stated, pandas would be simple--and pretty if you are using a Python notebook. Add this snippet below to your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(code, columns=['number', 'letter'])

# print or show
print(df.to_string(index=False)); df.set_index('number')
```

You will need to change the dict to a list:
`code = list(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))`

Comment: when i add this code and run it i get an empty table, is there something i need to add?

Comment: I'm really sorry about the delay @Dumknight, please see the updated answer.